# Ubuntu 19.04 Mouse Clicks Don't Work

Tags: keyboard, mouse, 19.04

I recently upgraded from Ubuntu 18.10 to Ubuntu 19.04 and the ordeal has left my mouse nonfunctional. In fact, all input devices are no longer functional except the keyboard. I'm using a Lenovo Yoga C930

The behavior is just odd.

On startup before login, everything works normally. After login, the computer simply doesn't respond to input (touch screen, mouse, and keyboard); however, if you close the laptop and then reopen it (no other way to force a lock screen), the keyboard starts to work again. The mouse does not start working.

If you open a few windows, many keyboard functions stop responding. You can still alt-tab to switch between windows and use the home key to display all windows; however, shortcuts to open a terminal or tabbing through windows no longer works.

I haven't seen anyone else have this problem and would rather not do a clean install. I'm not even sure if that would be possible for me.

Comment: You probably have a GNOME extension problem. Get to the Recovery Mode # prompt, and type `ls -al /home/username/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions`. Show me, or tell me, what you see there. I'm only interested in the filenames.

Comment: @heynnema I have this problem as well. My extensions: `appfolders-manager@maestroschan.fr`, `apt-update-indicator@franglais125.gmail.com`, `clipboard-indicator@tudmotu.com`, `cpupower@mko-sl.de`, `EasyScreenCast@iacopodeenosee.gmail.com`, `openweather-extension@jenslody.de`, `workspaces-to-dock@passingthru67.gmail.com`

Comment: @heynnema you solved it! it was a GNOME extension - not sure which tho cuz i just removed them all

Comment: @SterlingButters my guess would be `workspaces-to-dock`. Enable them one at a time to determine which one it really is.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue when the mouse was plugged into the laptop, even thought to reinstall Ubuntu, but noticed that when I unplug mouse, Gnome started to respond again with a touchpad. Then I plugged another mouse and it worked well. Now I'm thinking is it mouse (is it dying?) or something is with Ubuntu or Gnome drivers (Manjaro Live has the same issue) for SteelSeries Kana...